# Prevent tidy from adding html tags

Tags: php, html, forms, tidy

I have a class that generates some html (form elements and table elements), but this class returns all the html in one line.

So I am trying to use tidy to beautify the code (indent the code, put line breaks, etc), the only problem I am having is that's also generating the tags I don't want.

Here is the code:

```
tidy_parse_string(
                    $table->getHtml(),
                    array(
                            'DocType' => 'omit',
                            'indent' => true,
                            'indent-spaces' => 4,                                    
                            'wrap' => 0                                    
                        )
                );
```

The only way I have found to remove the extra html tags is by adding a str_replace, something like this:

```
str_replace(array('<html>','</html>','<body>','</body>','<head>','</head>','<title>','</title>'),'', code);
```

Which works, but I was really hopping there would be a way to tell tidy to just beautify the code and not insert the extra code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try the [show-body-only](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#show-body-only) option.

e.g.

```
$s = '<form method="post" action="?"><table><tr><td><input tpye="submit"></table>';
echo tidy_parse_string($s, array('show-body-only'=>true, 'indent'=>true));
```

prints

```
<form method="post" action="?">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input tpye="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

(string has been repaired and indented but no html/body wrapper added).
Can be combined with the [output-xhtml](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#output-xhtml) option which in this case would also add the slash for the empty input element.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that option. Thanks!!

Comment: Dear lord. This is exactly what I needed, but I never would have guessed it from the name of the option or even its description!

Comment: what if i want to load HTML but display it by XML? output-xml=true so show-body-only doesn't work. how to do in that case?

Comment: @ПавелИванов, `output-xml: true` overrides `show-body-only: yes/auto`. I don't think there's any way to prevent this behavior.