# HTML Tidy on partial files?

Tags: tidy

I've got a punch of Django template files that I want to use [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to clean up. However, it inserts all this doctype and header junk that I don't want. Mainly, I just want it to fix the indentation. All the other stuff is just extra.

Does tidy even work on partial files like this? What command can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963298/prevent-tidy-from-adding-html-tags/1963498#1963498).

Comment: more specifically http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#show-body-only thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Pretty Diff tool instead.  It is a far more completely algorithm and it operates on incomplete input without making any assumptions.

http://prettydiff.com/?m=beautify&html