# Notepad++ HTML Tidy Unknown Exception Windows 7 x64

Tags: notepad++, htmltidy

When I attempt to run HTML Tidy from the TextFX menu in NotePad++ (v5.9.3) I get the following error:

Config file "C:\Program Files(x86)\Notepad++\plugins\Config\tidy\HTMLTIDY.CFG" not found!  I'll pick whatever defaults I want to!

After I click OK I get:

"Unknown exception" and my cursor changes to the hourglass whenever I am in the document I was attempting to run HTMLTidy on.

The file exists in the location specified, I have tried changing the permissions on the file so Everyone has full control but that made no difference.

Answer (score 5):

**Windows 7 x64, Notepad++ 5.9.5 Solution:**

It has to do with the libTidy.dll not being included in the current distributions.
However, it was available in earlier versions.

Solution is to download the [5.9 zip](http://download.tuxfamily.org/notepadplus/5.9/npp.5.9.bin.zip), then
copy the  **ansi\plugins\Config\tidy** folder to your current **Notepad++\plugins\Config** folder

Also, if you install to the c:\Program Files or c:\Program Files (x86) directories, you will need to adjust the permissions on the tidy folder to allow non-administrator access

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809636/notepad-html-tidy/7935797#7935797), these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, they were similar questions and I felt the information would be helpful in both places.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Seems to be a bug. Wasted a few hours on this.

Ended up piping everything through the [Tidy online beatutifier](http://infohound.net/tidy/).