# Notepad++ 6.1.x and HTMLTidy

Tags: notepad++, htmltidy

Has someone got Notepad 6.1.x and HTMLTidy working and can tell me, where to download the dll / config. Using: Notepad++ 6.1.4 Win 7 x86

Yes, this Notepad++ / TidyHTML question has been already asked, but it either refers to outdated URLs, does not work with **newer Notepad++ 6.1. versions**, or does not work at all.

SO References:

1. [Format HTML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820811/format-html-document)
2. [Notepad++ HTML Tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809636/notepad-html-tidy)
3. [Notepad++ HTML Tidy Unknown Exception Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587372/notepad-html-tidy-unknown-exception-windows-7-x64)

Here is what I did:

1. Installed `TextFx` plugin as of `Plugins / PluginManager`: OK
2. Created default `tidycfg.ini` as of here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=HTML_Tidy
3. Downloaded `libtidy.dll` from here: http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?HTML_Tidy_for_Windows (some cr... ad pops up)

Now I got a HTMLTidy menu, but when I run it, it crashes. So I would need a different dll or another setup whatsoever.

[image: Menus are OK]
[image: Crash]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935797/356726

The 5.9 plugins worked for me with version 6.1.x of Notepad++, but even having the unicode version I had to use the ANSI plugin. The Unicode plugins crashed.

Comment: Bummer, this means you won't be able to format HTML with Unicode characters in it. A better solution would be to download the [latest HTML Tidy binary](http://binaries.html-tidy.org/) which supports HTML5 and use it with NppExec to format your HTML within Notepad++. Here's a tutorial on setting up Perl Tidy with NppExec, which is similar to how you would set up HTML Tidy: https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/format-your-perl-scripts-using-perltidy-and-notepad/

Answer (score 2):

Download old version notepad++ in zip format.

Copy from zip \unicode\plugins\Config\tidy
to C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\Config\tidy

restart notepad++ and now you have available the plug-in

Menu -> TextFX -> TextFX HTML Tidy –> Tidy: Reindent XML

Link to download old version whit the plugin
http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.6.8.html