# indent pre existing code in notepad

Tags: notepad++

I am looking for a way to take code someone sends me in HTML and indent it accordingly.  It would appear I receive code by multiple editors and it annoys me that it's not structured correctly or not indented.  when I do A Google [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=indent%20in%20notepadd%2b%2b&oq=indent%20in%20notepadd%2b%2b&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&spell=1&q=indent%20pre%20existing%20code%20in%20notepad%2b%2b&sa=X&ei=BNwTUcvtJIS49QTs6oGgAQ&ved=0CCwQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=5abf6276490b67b7&biw=931&bih=618) nothing pops up.  I have seen how to auto-indent like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412427/auto-indent-in-notepad) but Im trying to correct the issue after it has been coded.

Comment: there's tools that clean up code, but only for specific languages, e.g. `cb` for C beautification.

Comment: so basically you are saying there is not one solid way to highlight the code and hit indent or a complete plugin that will do it?

Comment: no. different languages have different formatting rules. e.g. something that'll beautify PHP or C will probably totally destroy a Python script.

Comment: The format and amount of code indenting varies from one person to the next. For JS and HTML you can use: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called HTMLTidy that can indent HTML. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591532/notepad-6-1-x-and-htmltidy) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809636/notepad-html-tidy/7935797#7935797) for information on how to get it working on newer versions of Notepad++.

Comment: thanks for the fix, i didn't mention this myself because i never had the dll and couldn't use the tool