# Plugin for Organize Tags

Tags: plugins, tags, alignment, dreamweaver, notepad++

anyone know any plugin for any program (eg dreamweaver, notepad + +), which organizes the tags and aligns it all?

eg:

before:

```
<body>
<div>
         <ul>
                 <li> </ li>
                                 <li> </ li>
         <li> </ li>
</ ul>
                 </ div>
         </ body>
```

then:

```
<body>
         <div>
                 <ul>
                         <li> </ li>
                         <li> </ li>
                         <li> </ li>
                 </ ul>
         </ div>
</ body>
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Notepad++ plugin TextFX HTMLTidy.

Unfortunately in recent releases of Notepad++ this plugin is not set up correctly for some reason, but check the solution by Noah here: [Notepad++ HTML Tidy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809636/notepad-html-tidy) for instructions on how to get it up and running: