# Notepad++ HTML Tidy Unknown Exception Windows 7 x32

Tags: notepad++, htmltidy

When I attempt to run HTML Tidy from the TextFX menu in NotePad++ (v6.5.5) I get the following error:

Config file "C:\Program Files(x86)\Notepad++\plugins\Config\tidy\HTMLTIDY.CFG" not found! I'll pick whatever defaults I want to!

After I click OK I get:

"Unknown exception" and my cursor changes to the hourglass whenever I am in the document I was attempting to run HTMLTidy on.

The file doesn't exist in the location specified... 
what next to do? plz help someone

Comment: related: [Notepad++ HTML Tidy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/809636/1699210)